# Свое изображение в редакторе многоугольника

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Можно ли сделать опцию выбора изображения вместо фонового цвета в редакторе многоугольников? Если да, то как, помогите прошу

Comment: Наверное, от редактора зависит

Comment: Я про АПИ Яндекса Карты

Answer (score 1):

В качестве заливки полигона можно использовать своё изображение.
Для этого нужно указать опции  [fillImageHref](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/GeoObject-docpage/?from=SO#param-options.fillMethod) и [fillMethod](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/GeoObject-docpage/?from=SO#param-options.fillMethod).

[Пример в песочнице Яндекса](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon_with_image?from=SO)

Comment: Это я знаю, как добавить это в редактор многоугольника или редактор полигона

Comment: Тогда я не очень понимаю вопрос, что значит добавить в редактор)
Можно выставлять эти опции и в режиме редактирования: https://jsfiddle.net/kvdph45q/1/ Пример можно докрутить, чтобы выбирать картинку самому.

Если нужно настраивать внешний вид элементов редактора (маркеров вершин), то такой пример тоже есть: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/editor_icon_layout Для полигона будет аналогично

Comment: Извините, да не понятно задал вопрос, я про этот редактор - https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygonEditor. Но вопрос в том как на самой карте создать инструмент (элемент управления), который позволит менять фон многоугольника на собственное изображение (либо загружаемое, либо из списка) А первый пример хорош, уже хоть что то, спасибо

Comment: Тогда Вам нужен свой элемент управления, в котором можно будет выбирать изображение для заливки полигона. При выборе картинки из списка, просто применяйте опции, как в моём примере.

Comment: А можете ли вы подсказать пример, где элемент управления не сразу на карте, а в балуне. То есть при нажатие на полигон, появляется балун а там кнопки. Я просто не очень пока силен в апи яндекса. А что бы загружать своё изображение на карту, нужны какие нибудь дополнительные функции? Ведь изображение будет куда то сохраняться

Comment: Например, вот: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_balloon_layout

В опции указывается url изображение, либо оно сохраняется где-то у Вас в ресурсах проекта, либо выложено в интернете. Но как именно это делать, уже выбирайте самостоятельно. На API это не повлияет.